# Restart AnimatorSet of AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, animatorset

This is I need Realized effect by `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`.

**vector_drawable_anim.xml**

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable">
    <target
        android:name="star"
        android:animation="@animator/star_anim"/>
</animated-vector>
```

**vector_drawable.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="500px"
        android:height="500px"
        android:viewportHeight="500"
        android:viewportWidth="500">
    <group
        android:name="star_group"
        android:scaleX="5.0"
        android:scaleY="5.0">
        <path
            android:name="star"
            android:pathData="M 50.0,90.0 L 82.9193546357,27.2774101308 L 12.5993502926,35.8158045183 Z"
            android:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    </group>
</vector>
```

**star_anim.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ordering="sequentially">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"/>

</set>
```

But the `AnimatorSet` can't set `repeatMode`.

If I set `objectAnimator`'s `repeatMode`, the second `objectAnimator` won't show.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616444/how-to-reset-objectanimator-to-its-initial-status

Comment: or add android:repeatCount="-1"

 `<objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:repeatCount="-1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about looping it inside a thread until the ImageView is destroyed?

Perfectly working code sample:

```
  ImageView animatedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
  AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVectorDrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) animatedImageView.getDrawable();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (animatedImageView != null) {
                    try {
                        animatedImageView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                animatedVectorDrawable.start();
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Alternatively, you can use the **registerAnimationCallback()** mentioned by **azizbekian** followed by [this git gist code sample](https://gist.github.com/nickbutcher/97143b3240682e5c5851fe45b49fde93):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Animatable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Animatable2;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pin);
        final AnimatedVectorDrawable avd = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
        avd.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                avd.start();
            }
        });
        avd.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use post to delay avd.start() , It can work. I think it maybe was a bug when at onAnimationEnd() the animator isRunning!

Comment: Yes! I've personally tested it with working results. @csx

Comment: If I am using your first method, I am getting - Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable cannot be cast to androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat

The Second method is available from 23+.

Comment: @AmanVerma AnimatedVectorDrawable is from android.graphics and AnimatedVectorDrawable is from androidx.vectordrawable. You have mixed up an androix widget with android widget. Check your imports and layout.

Answer (score 2):

Almost what you want, and in pure XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1" />

</set>
```

The difference from what you want is the direction of the path trimming back. But it looks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a listener on animation and as soon as it finishes [`start()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html#start()) it once more:

```
    AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat avdc = ...;
    avdc.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
            avdc.start();
        }
    });
```

Note, that [`registerAnimationCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html#registerAnimationCallback(android.support.graphics.drawable.Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback)) is available starting from support libs version 25.3.0.

Comment: I can't find the Animatable2Compat,how to load Animatable2Compat

Comment: It is available starting from support libs version `25.3.0`.

Comment: but the AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat use ObjectAnimator below 21 and the AnimatorSet wouldn't repeat .

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean. Can you rephrase? How does updating support library version conflict with "below 21" functionality?

Comment: I mean It can't repeat the Animated at android-19.